# does anyone have a C# solution to retrieve data from the Sharepoint List Data Retrieval Service

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-services

i am trying to download data from a sharepoint list from a C# application.  I see there is a webservice to connect to here:

```
http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/dspsts.asmx
```

which is the  List Data Retrieval Service.  But i can't find any example code on basics like:

- how do i specify the list and page i want to download from
- basic logging in
- retrieving and parsing the data results

any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you are just trying to get the Items out of a SharePoint List.
You only have to add the webservice and use the Lists.GetListItems Method.

MSDN provides an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx

Comment: @creek - thanks for the pointer . . do you how to determine what "Web_Reference_Folder" should be.  I am bringing in the web service proxy through Visual studio but I dont see anything that has a "ListService"

Comment: Try to use http://<site>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx (the Lists Webservice) not dspsts.asmx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CMIS technology and  it will get u all data from SharePoint :
here is a link abt the technology details :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934619.aspx